# after ubuntu 16.04 upgrade, certain key doesn't have "keypress" event

Tags: keyboard, 16.04

well, I just now upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04

I find out "v" is not working properly.

after run `xev`, it looks like, unlike other normal keys, it only has "KeyRelease event".

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0xc4, subw 0x0, time 429479, (123,58), root:(173,547),
    state 0x0, keycode 55 (keysym 0x76, v), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (76) "v"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

However, it'll be working for long press.

By following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting, I believe it's about dot files.

I've created another account and login, "v" is working. (also working in the password field of login window).

I've deleted many dot files about gnome, but still not working.

any help would be really appreciated!

[image: gconf-editor]

Answer (score 0):

oh, I check out my startup application list and after some tests, I find out it's diodon. I uninstall it and v works again.